# data operations with grouping on ListView nativescript vuejs

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, telerik, nativescript

Well as it seems the docs on the RadListView component using vuejs from telerik misses the data operations.

I need to get a contact list with the appropriate headers.

Those are the the functions I need:
[Docs from Telerik on ListView](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/data-operations)

```
data = [{name: 'Alice', foo: 'data'}, {name: 'bob', foo:'data'}]
```

How do you do it with Vuejs?

Result i'm after [Result](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1016)

Comment: Group (section) header is a iOS specific feature, implemented by [nativescript-sectioned-list-view](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-sectioned-list-view) plugin. An easy way to mock this feature for iOS & Android would be, include an item template that would look like group (section) header, inject a data item at right position of your data array which will represent the header view. Also remember to ignore itemTap event when source is the header view.

Comment: Do you know how the RadListView with grouping works for vuejs?

Comment: What are you exactly looking for, is it the grouping function / group items by header?

Comment: Yes that is what i'm looking for